# SQL Server temporary table split string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement to read a file into memory and pass the string into a stored procedure.

I am required to split each new line of that string into a new row in a temporary database for processing.

Does anyone have a function that will convert a big string (1000 line) each line with around 500 characters into a temporary database.

Thanks

Comment: how does the string look like?

Comment: The string is a less file which is a little difficult. Anyways I needed to escape single quotes from the text to ensure it went in ok. I used something similar to the function below.

Answer (score 3):

Create a split function (this one will handle strings up to about 4.5 million characters, depending on the version of SQL Server):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitStrings_Ordered]
(
    @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN (SELECT [Index] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Number), Item 
    FROM (SELECT Number, Item = SUBSTRING(@List, Number, 
      CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @List + @Delimiter, Number) - Number)
     FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])
      FROM sys.all_objects AS s1 CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2) AS n(Number)
      WHERE Number <= CONVERT(INT, LEN(@List))
      AND SUBSTRING(@Delimiter + @List, Number, LEN(@Delimiter)) = @Delimiter
    ) AS y);
```

So then you pass the string in and say:

```
SELECT LineNumber = [Index], Line = Item
INTO #temp
FROM dbo.SplitStrings_Ordered(@StringParameter, CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)) AS x;
```

You may have to play with `CHAR(10)` and `CHAR(13)` - how CR/LF are stored in the file may vary depending on where they came from.

Comment: My almost empty database has around 2000 records in `sys.all_objects`. Will it be enough in all cases?

Comment: If your text file has <= 4,000,000 characters (2,000 ^ 2), yes. If there is a chance your string will be more than 4,000,000 characters, then you can use `sys.all_columns` instead (in one spot or both). That will support up to about 71,000,000 characters. If that's still not enough, stop trying to break apart such strings in SQL Server. Even 4,000,000 should be handled externally (C# will be much more efficient than SQL Server).